# FastAPI: How to map arbitrary-attribute dict to pydantic model to let swagger display detail

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastAPI project that one of its endpoint looks like this:

```py
@app.post(
    response=SomePydanticModel() # how to compose SomePydanticModel here???
)
def my_end_point():
    response = {
        "ZOOQ-700Z71": [
            {"product_id": "prod_001", "product_name": "Product 001", "quantity": 10},
            {"product_id": "prod_002", "product_name": "Product 002", "quantity": 20},
            {"product_id": "prod_004", "product_name": "Product 004", "quantity": 30},
        ],
        "0071-ZOGKNQ": [
            {"product_id": "prod_001", "product_name": "Product 001", "quantity": 10},
            {"product_id": "prod_003", "product_name": "Product 003", "quantity": 7},
            {"product_id": "prod_008", "product_name": "Product 008", "quantity": 2},
        ],
        "0071-Z0GKQ7": [
            {"product_id": "prod_002", "product_name": "Product 002", "quantity": 12},
            {"product_id": "prod_007", "product_name": "Product 007", "quantity": 6},
        ],
        "ZZOQ-ZXOCT9": [
            {"product_id": "prod_004", "product_name": "Product 004", "quantity": 100},
        ],
        "2007-ZCKOZR": [
            {"product_id": "prod_004", "product_name": "Product 004", "quantity": 30},
            {"product_id": "prod_005", "product_name": "Product 005", "quantity": 20},
        ],
    }
```

As you can see that my response is arbitrary-attribute dict, its attributes formatted `xxxx-xxxxxx` are **Purchase Order ID**. How can I write `SomePydanticModel` to represent my response? Therefore, I want the swagger to show the description of my response.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a model with `Dict` as [root type](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) with keys as [constrained](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr) string `constr` with regex pattern.

For example:

```
from typing import Dict, List

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

app = FastAPI()


class Product(BaseModel):
    product_id: str
    product_name: str
    quantity: int


ConStrType = constr(regex=r'^[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{6}$')
ProductDict = Dict[ConStrType, List[Product]]


class ProductModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: ProductDict



@app.post("/products", response_model=ProductModel)
def my_end_point():
    return {
        "ZOOQ-700Z71": [
            {"product_id": "prod_001", "product_name": "Product 001", "quantity": 10},
            {"product_id": "prod_002", "product_name": "Product 002", "quantity": 20},
            {"product_id": "prod_004", "product_name": "Product 004", "quantity": 30},
        ],
        "0071-ZOGKNQ": [
            {"product_id": "prod_001", "product_name": "Product 001", "quantity": 10},
            {"product_id": "prod_003", "product_name": "Product 003", "quantity": 7},
            {"product_id": "prod_008", "product_name": "Product 008", "quantity": 2},
        ],
        "0071-Z0GKQ7": [
            {"product_id": "prod_002", "product_name": "Product 002", "quantity": 12},
            {"product_id": "prod_007", "product_name": "Product 007", "quantity": 6},
        ],
        "ZZOQ-ZXOCT9": [
            {"product_id": "prod_004", "product_name": "Product 004", "quantity": 100},
        ],
        "2007-ZCKOZR": [
            {"product_id": "prod_004", "product_name": "Product 004", "quantity": 30},
            {"product_id": "prod_005", "product_name": "Product 005", "quantity": 20},
        ],
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, how could I embed `title` or `description` to ConStrType? I can do it with `product_id`, `product_name` and `quantity` via `Field` class but for `ConStrType` I cannot do the same thing with.

Comment: Can you give an example of what json schema you want for custom keys?

Comment: For now, I can only suggest that you [customize](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#schema-customization) the scheme for the entire model.

Comment: this is what I expect for `Purchase Order ID` {
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^([A-Z]\\d){4}-([A-Z]\\d){6}$": {
      "description": "Purchase Order detail, specified by Purchase Order ID. First 4 digits are lot number.",
      "type": "array",
      ...
      }
    }
  }
}  I cannot see the way to construct the class with arbitrary class attributes.

Comment: The `patternProperties` keyword is [not supported](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/?sbsearch=patternproperties) in Openapi 3.0.x, which is used by fastapi 0.68 and swagger UI as of today. But you can add this manually using [`schema_extra`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#schema-customization)